# HttpGet returns 500 error if port is specified

Tags: java, http

One of our devs reported the following error.

```
HttpGet foo = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/path/to/file.xml");
```

works fine.

However, if the port is specified,

```
HttpGet foo = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com:80/path/to/file.xml");
```

the server returns a HTTP 500 error.

I've already verified that the website runs on the standard HTTP port 80. What could be the reason of this behavior? It looks like it's server side, as both lines of code work fine towards other websites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache HttpClient and custom ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712505/apache-httpclient-and-custom-ports)

Comment: @AxelH Possibly not or does the HttpClient switch to chunked transfer automatically if you add port to the URL?

Comment: @AxelH And the feedback to that answer was that it still leads to "error 400 bad request". So obviously that didn't work and it's about a completely different type of error than this question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look into the server's log should bring up more information what exactly is going wrong there (status code 500 means that the server ran into a problem) but my guess is that there is some kind of script configured behind the URL that processes that value of the HTTP-request-header `Host`, doesn't expect the port-specification and runs into an error because of this.

Another reason might be a proxy between you and the server that ran into an error but I found that more hard to believe than the above theory.

Please provide the error-log of the server in order to be able to say more about this.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have access to the remote server `www.example.com` so troubleshooting is very limited.  But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @dr01 You might ask the owner of the server if they can tell you more. To rule out your code, you migth just try to use the second URL with the port-specification in your browser. If you see the same error, it's definitely a problem on the server. If it works it might still be one if the browser recognizes the standard port and omits it in the request.